# Assigning values to character arrays inside of a structure array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, char

I am new to C++, but very familiar with Python. Trivial tasks in Python seem to be much more complex in C++. I am attempting to make a simple game where a word in a foreign language is printed on screen, the user guesses the value, if correct they are awarded a point and continue guessing what the value of other numbers printed on screen are. The problem I am facing that for the course I am taking we are not allowed to use strings only character arrays. The reason for this has not been explained by the instructor.

In Python, I would create a tuple of strings for the foreign word numbers:

```
foreignWords = ('een', 'twee', 'drie'....)
```

index 0 would be the word for one in Dutch, index 1 would be the word for two in Dutch, etc. I would use a function to randomly select a number between 0 and the length of foreignWords, print it on screen, etc. Very simple to do.

I thought I could simply create a structure array and strcopy the char arrays into the struct array.

```
    struct numbers
    {
      char numberWord[7];
    };


    int main()
    {
      numbers numberChoices[10];
      strcpy(numberChoices[0].numberWord, 'een');
      strcpy(numberChoices[1].numberWord, 'twee');
      strcpy(numberChoices[2].numberWord, 'drie');
      strcpy(numberChoices[3].numberWord, 'vier');
      strcpy(numberChoices[4].numberWord, 'vijf'):
      strcpy(numberChoices[5].numberWord, 'zes');

      etc.
```

That doesn't work though. It produces an error:

```
    string.h:129:14: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^
```

However, if I create a for-loop and input the char array via cin >> the structure array will store my entries and they can be called by index.

Essentially, what I would like to do is make an array of char arrays that way I can an index get the value back and trivially keep track of the numerical value of the word (numberChoices[i].numberWord, i+1 = numerical value of the printed word). I don't know if this appropriate approach or not, but I am trying to be efficient, because the structure array would be referenced quite a bit to read what is stored in memory, save that value to a new variable and manipulate the referenced char array by deleting characters randomly and having the user guess what value the printed words.

What is the correct way to go about making an array of char arrays where the char array elements are hard coded?

Comment: In c++ strings are enclosed in double quotes: `"foo"`. Single quotes are only for characters.

Comment: In C++ you would use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Also, a single `char` is a *single `char`*, it can only fit one single character not a string.

Comment: "we are not allowed to use strings only character arrays." Your instructor explicitly banned something like `char const* numberchoices[] = { "een", "twie", "drie", "vier" };` but wrapping a char array inside a struct is somehow a-ok?

Comment: Voted to close as simply typo (using `'` instead of `"`).

Comment: Dan, looks like you caught my issue; changing 'word' to "word" fixed my problem.

Comment: You can do **`char const* foreignWords [] = { "een", "twie", "drie", "vier" };`** as already remarked by @user657267.

Comment: @user657267, they haven't explained why we can't use strings and only char arrays. Structures weren't explicitly disallowed, so here I am.

Answer (score 2):

Your code syntax is worng. You must represent char arrays as `"abc"`, but not like `'abc'`.

So your code must be like:

```
  numbers numberChoices[10];
  strcpy(numberChoices[0].numberWord, "een");
  strcpy(numberChoices[1].numberWord, "twee");
  strcpy(numberChoices[2].numberWord, "drie");
  strcpy(numberChoices[3].numberWord, "vier");
  strcpy(numberChoices[4].numberWord, "vijf"):
  strcpy(numberChoices[5].numberWord, "zes");
```

Secondly you must remember that char arrays like `"een"` have extra char called null terminate `'\0'` so you must define array with enough size to store your characters and that extra character. That concept is called **'null terminating string'**.

`'\0'` character is required to properly define your string size in functions like `strcpy`, `strlen` e. t. c. because you can not know about array size only by pointer to its first element (all array literals are considered like pointers in C/C++).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is a distinction between single and double quotes: single quotes denote a single *character literal*, e.g. 'a', '0', '\n' while double quotes are used for c-strings, e.g. "a.u.b".

So replace

```
  strcpy(numberChoices[0].numberWord, 'een');
```

with

```
  strcpy(numberChoices[0].numberWord, "een");
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the quote mix-up pointed out by others, you can take advantage static initialization to make some of that work go away.

```
struct numbers
{
  char numberWord[7];
};


numbers numberChoices[10] =
{
    {"een"},
    {"twee"},
    {"drie"},
    {"vier"},
    {"vijf"},
    {"zes"},
    ...
};
int main()
{
    std::cout << numberChoices[1].numberWord << std::endl;
}
```

And if possible within the constraints of your assignment, a further simplification:

```
const char * numberChoices[] =
{
    "een",
    "twee",
    "drie",
    "vier",
    "vijf",
    "zes",
    ...
};
int main()
{
    std::cout << numberChoices[1] << std::endl;
}
```

It would seem that `std::string` is off the table for you. Pity. Use it where possible. It will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

avoid c-style strings. use the c++ concepts:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

struct numbers
{
  std::string numberWord;
};

int main()
{
  numbers numberChoices[] = {
        { "een" },
        { "twee" },
        { "drie" },
        { "vier" },
        { "vijf" },
        { "zes" },
        // ... etc
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore your course requirestments for a moment;

You shouldn't use any magic indexes! use map instead, with meaningful keys;

With a proper map and string usage your code could look similar to this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using foreign_word = std::string;
using foreign_words = std::vector<foreign_word>;

using language = std::string;
using language_words_map = std::unordered_map<language, foreign_words>;

int main() {
    language_words_map lwm = {
        { "deutch", {"een", "twee", "drie"} },
        /* ... and so on */
    };
    return 0;
}
```

see: http://ideone.com/BI6QjL